# Jquery Mobile ListView showing a wrong scroll inside it

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, jsf-2.2

I'm just creating a simple list with a button and a chart using google chart, but it's happening

[image]

It create a little scroll at right of the listview.

This is my code:

```
<ul data-role="listview" class="ui-nodisc-icon ui-alt-icon" data-divider-theme="c" style="margin-top: 20px;" >
<li >
    <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-mini ui-btn-c ui-icon-arrow-r ui-btn-icon-right" onclick="window.location.href='meta_grafico_empresa.xhtml?cd_meta=11';" style="text-align: center;" >Geral</a>
    <a href="#" >
        <div id="chart_div" style="height: 380px; width: 100%;"></div>
    </a>
</li>
```

Comment: From the image it is hard to tell which DOM element is actually getting the scrollbar. Can you make this happen in a jsFiddle? or tell us which DOM element is overflowing and what CSS is active?